# How do I display % Relative Freq instead of Freq

Tags: r

I have a roulette wheel simulation that plots a frequency versus roulette wheel slot (or factor) but I would also like to view % relative frequency vs. factor.

```
black_on_wheel = paste("B", 1:18, sep = "") 
red_on_wheel = paste("R", 1:18, sep = "")
roulette_wheel = c(red_on_wheel, black_on_wheel, "0", "00")
simulated_roulette_wheel = sample(roulette_wheel, size=500, replace = TRUE)
plot(rw_runs)
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. What is `rw_runs`? Have you even considered `table` and `prop.table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @joran pointed out, you can use `table` and `prop.table`:

```
set.seed(001) # For the simulation to be reproducible.
simulated_roulette_wheel = sample(roulette_wheel, size=500, replace = TRUE)

tab <-table(simulated_roulette_wheel)                  # Frequency of each factor
prop.tab <- prop.table(tab) * 100                      # % Relative Freq.
barplot(prop.tab, xaxs='i', ylab="Relative %") ; box() # Barplot
```

In `barplot`, `xaxs="i"` allows the bars to start at the origin in x coordinate and the function `box()` adds a box to the plot.

The first ten elements of `prop.tab` looks like:

```
prop.tab[1:10]
simulated_roulette_wheel
  0  00  B1 B10 B11 B12 B13 B14 B15 B16 
2.4 2.8 4.6 3.4 2.2 3.0 1.8 2.4 2.2 2.2
```

If you don't multiply `prop.table(tab)` by 100, then you will only obtain a proportion instead of relative percentage.

Here's the barplot generated:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
rw_runs <- table( simulated_roulette_wheel)
str(rw_runs)
# 'table' int [1:38(1d)] 19 9 13 8 19 16 12 11 14 13 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
#  ..$ simulated_roulette_wheel: chr [1:38] "0" "00" "B1" "B10" ...
 barplot( rw_runs*100/sum(rw_runs) )
```